# Mongodb: Cannot see data of the Embedded Document via command

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

For **mongodb's embedded document**, I don't know why the **data is not saved in the database** or something else might be wrong? I tried to print out everything to make sure it works till the last step. But still got nothing when querying the embedded document, as you can see from below.

My schema:

```
// create competitorAnalysisSchema
var CompetitorAnalysis = new Schema({
    firstObservation: { type: String },
    secondObservation: { type: String },
    thirdObservation: { type: String },
    brandName: { type: String },
    productCategory: { type: String },
    photo1: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
    photo2: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
    photo3: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
    photo4: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }
});

// create UserSchema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    userName: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    currentDemo: { type: String },
    nextDemo: { type: String },
    startTime: { type: String },
    startLocation: { type: String },
    arriveTime: { type: String },
    arriveLocation: { type: String },
    leaveTime: { type: String },
    leaveLocation: { type: String },
    competitorAnalysis: [CompetitorAnalysis],
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

In my index.js, all debug messages can be successfully printed out.:

```
// on routes that end in /users/competitorAnalysisTextData
// ----------------------------------------------------
router.route('/users/competitorAnalysisTextData/:userName')

    // update the user info (accessed at PUT http://localhost:8080/api/users/competitorAnalysisTextData)
    .put(function(req, res) {

        // use our user model to find the user we want
        User.findOne({ userName: req.params.userName}, function(err, user) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            console.log('Got the user!');

            // update the text data
            user.competitorAnalysis.firstObservation = req.body.firstObservation;
            user.competitorAnalysis.secondObservation = req.body.secondObservation;
            user.competitorAnalysis.thirdObservation = req.body.thirdObservation;
            user.competitorAnalysis.brandName = req.body.brandName;
            user.competitorAnalysis.productCategory = req.body.productCategory;
            console.log('req.body.firstObservation: %s', req.body.firstObservation);
            console.log('user.competitorAnalysis.firstObservation: %s', user.competitorAnalysis.firstObservation);
            console.log('Save the text data for competitorAnalysisTextData!');

            // save the user
            user.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json({ message: 'User updated!' });
                console.log('user.competitorAnalysis.firstObservation: %s', user.competitorAnalysis.firstObservation);
                console.log('Finally save the User!');
            });

        });
    })
```

As in console:

```
Got the user in "Put"!
req.body.firstObservation: 3
user.competitorAnalysis.firstObservation: 3
Save the text data for competitorAnalysisTextData!
user.competitorAnalysis.firstObservation: 3
Finally save the User!
```

**Problem**

However, when I search in my mongodb database, there is no data saved for the embedded document:

```
...
"leaveTime" : "Your Current Time:\n 2016-08-23 10:27:45 AM",
"leaveLocation" : "Your Current Address:\n 1\nInfinite Loop\nCupertino\n95014",
"competitorAnalysis" : [ ]
}
> db.users.find({"competitorAnalysis.firstObservation" : "3"}).pretty()
>
```

Empty here!

I'm new to mongodb. It'll be great if I can get some hints on where else I can check or what the problem might be.

**Update**

Output of collection:

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ba5f41ad8858305a5d3e58"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2016-08-22T02:11:13.968Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-08-24T19:42:56.311Z"),
    "nextDemo" : "12:00pm - 3:00pm, Whole Foods Market, 5880 Centre Ave, Pittsburgh PA 15206",
    "currentDemo" : "9:00am - 1:00pm,  Whole Foods Market, 5880 Centre Ave, Pittsburgh PA 15206",
    "password" : "<3da4dafc c96e05cd 855da8b3 ff0bf074 8156ec4b b9f1a002 ba907bcc d5e4aa5b fcd2fef9 dec240cd 86489978 7d85cec8 f11eae1c 7b60b2cc 6693da1a 4eae3a73>",
    "email" : "chenya@gmail.com",
    "userName" : "Chenya",
    "__v" : 1,
    "startLocation" : "Your Current Address:\n 10141\nBilich Pl\nCupertino\n95014",
    "startTime" : "Your Current Time:\n 2016-08-24 03:42:42 PM",
    "arriveTime" : "Your Arriving Time:\n 2016-08-24 03:42:44 PM",
    "arriveLocation" : "Your Arriving Address:\n 10131\nBilich Pl\nCupertino\n95014",
    "leaveTime" : "Your Current Time:\n 2016-08-23 10:27:45 AM",
    "leaveLocation" : "Your Current Address:\n 1\nInfinite Loop\nCupertino\n95014",
    "competitorAnalysis" : [ ]
}
>
```

Comment: can you please post the output of your collection ? something like db.users.find();  I am not familiar with mongoose-schema but once I see the collection structure i might be able to help

Comment: Yes! I just updated my post with the output of collection. The last line is the embedded document. btw. Do you know anyway to query mongodb to list all embedded documents without specifying any field to match? I didn't find any from its doc... @user641887

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These statements are the problem:

```
    user.competitorAnalysis.firstObservation = req.body.firstObservation;
    user.competitorAnalysis.secondObservation = req.body.secondObservation;
    user.competitorAnalysis.thirdObservation = req.body.thirdObservation;
    user.competitorAnalysis.brandName = req.body.brandName;
    user.competitorAnalysis.productCategory = req.body.productCategory;
```

You're treating your competitorAnalysis array as if it were an object.

I don't work with Mongoose, so don't know the syntax, but you want to do something like this instead:

```
user.competitorAnalysis.push({
    firstObservation: req.body.firstObservation,
    secondObservation: req.body.secondObservation,
    thirdObservation: req.body.thirdObservation,
    brandName: req.body.brandName
    productCategory: req.body.productCategory
});
```